# Control when <Audio> plays and stops via Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I'm attempting to make several audio elements in html that will play music when I tell them to via javascript.

Here's my html:

```
<div id="pixelbutton" onClick="musicplay1()"> </div>

<audio id="song1" src="audio/ruins.wav" autostart=false hidden=true> </audio>
```

And my Javascript:

```
function musicplay1() {
var song1 = document.getElementById("song1");
song1.setAttribute('autostart', 'true');
}
```

The audio is for a good reason, so please spare me the "Oh god, really!? You're putting sound on a webpage? That's really annoying." comments.

Question is: How can I feasibly create a function in javascript that controls when my html audio tag plays?

I'm rather new to JavaScript, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'll give you an "Oh god, really!?" for saying you're new to java when you're talking about JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't asked a question, but I can see a couple of things to improve:

- `autostart` and `hidden` are boolean attributes, but that doesn't mean you should treat them like boolean variables. If the attribute is present then it is considered on, otherwise it's considered off. There is no attribute `hidden` - an `<audio>` element is only shown if the `controls` attribute is set. Additionally, you should tell the browser what type of audio you're using. So, your audio tag should be:

```
<audio id="song1" src="audio/ruins.wav" type="audio/x-wav" />
```

- It's bad practice to create a function that only works for one instance. You would be better off passing the `1` as a parameter, so you would have:

```
<div id="pixelbutton" onClick="musicplay(1);"> </div>
```

- Just setting the `autostart` attribute probably won't make it automatically start. Instead, use the `.play()` method. With this and the above point, you get:

```
function musicplay(id) {
    document.getElementById('song'+id).play();
}
```

- Finally, unless things have changed since I last checked, only IE and Firefox support WAV, Chrome does not.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Actually HTML5 defines a hidden attribute on all elements. http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/editing.html#the-hidden-attribute